# SentenceTransformers throwing KeyError on pandas Series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sentence-transformers

I'm using the following simplified code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
```

where `sentences` is a pandas `Series`, containing the sentences I want to transform.

and then I'm getting the following error Traceback

```
embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
File "/anaconda/envs/topics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 157, in encode
sentences_sorted = [sentences[idx] for idx in length_sorted_idx]
File "/anaconda/envs/topics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 157, in <listcomp>
sentences_sorted = [sentences[idx] for idx in length_sorted_idx]
File "/anaconda/envs/topics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 942, in 
__getitem__
return self._get_value(key)
File "/anaconda/envs/topics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1051, in 
_get_value
loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
File "/anaconda/envs/topics/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 144
```

Answer (score 4):

The actual solution was to convert the pandas `Series` to a `numpy` array:

```
sentences_array = sentences.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, what worked was `doing df['COLUMN'].to_list()` instead of  `df['COLUMN'].values` or  `df['COLUMN'].to_numpy()`

Answer (score 0):

The Embeddings will give in the form of array or Tensor form so use the following codes to solve this issue

```py
embeddings = model.encode(sentences, convert_to_tensor=True)
```

or

```py
embeddings = model.encode(sentences, convert_to_numpy=True)
```